# Find all values of 'a' such that given set is a basis of R4?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

- This is the given set { [1 2 1 3] , [3 4 1 1] , [7 5 a 6] , [1 4 2 a+1] } where we need to find 'a' such that the set is a basis of R4. These are in matrix form with dimension 4 x 1.

I proved these sets to be linearly independent and showed that it spans but that didn't help me find the values of 'a'. Am i going right because i still cannot figure out how do i use my work to find the value of 'a'.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried using a row-reduction argument?  Find the rank of the set if it were considered a $4\times 3$ (or $4\times 4$ in the case of part b) matrix with each column as one of the vectors in your set.  Also, for the record, you can visit [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn how to type matrices such as $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}3\\4\\2\\7\end{smallmatrix}\right]$

Comment: Oh, you mean using gauss-jordan elimination to reach to reduced raw echelon form and then using back substitution to find 'a'?

Comment: There is no "k" to find in this question.  There should be a theorem that you learned that says $Rank(A) = dim(Col(A)) = Rank(A^T) = dim(Row(A))=\text{number of independent columns of}~A=\text{number of pivots in rref of}~A=\dots$  Noting what $a$ makes it so that $A$ has full column rank (possibly none or all or a select few) is the same as finding what $a$ makes it so that the vectors are independent.